# Split data.frame based on levels of a factor into new data.frames

Tags: r, dataframe, r-faq

I'm trying to create separate `data.frame` objects based on levels of a factor. So if I have:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x=rnorm(25),
  y=rnorm(25),
  g=rep(factor(LETTERS[1:5]), 5)
)
```

How can I split `df` into separate `data.frame`s for each level of `g` containing the corresponding `x` and `y` values?  I can get most of the way there using `split(df, df$g)`, but I'd like the each level of the factor to have its own `data.frame`.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

I think that `split` does exactly what you want.

Notice that X is a list of data frames, as seen by `str`:

```
X <- split(df, df$g)
str(X)
```

If you want individual object with the group g names you could assign the elements of X from `split` to objects of those names, though this seems like extra work when you can just index the data frames from the list `split` creates.

```
#I used lapply just to drop the third column g which is no longer needed.
Y <- lapply(seq_along(X), function(x) as.data.frame(X[[x]])[, 1:2]) 

#Assign the dataframes in the list Y to individual objects
A <- Y[[1]]
B <- Y[[2]]
C <- Y[[3]]
D <- Y[[4]]
E <- Y[[5]]

#Or use lapply with assign to assign each piece to an object all at once
lapply(seq_along(Y), function(x) {
    assign(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")[x], Y[[x]], envir=.GlobalEnv)
    }
)
```

**Edit** Or even better than using `lapply` to assign to the global environment use `list2env`:

```
names(Y) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
list2env(Y, envir = .GlobalEnv)
A
```

Answer (score 21):

Since `dplyr 0.8.0` , we can also use `group_split` which has similar behavior as `base::split`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_split(g)

#[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#       x      y g    
#   <dbl>  <dbl> <fct>
#1 -1.21  -1.45  A    
#2  0.506  1.10  A    
#3 -0.477 -1.17  A    
#4 -0.110  1.45  A    
#5  0.134 -0.969 A    

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#       x      y g    
#   <dbl>  <dbl> <fct>
#1  0.277  0.575 B    
#2 -0.575 -0.476 B    
#3 -0.998 -2.18  B    
#4 -0.511 -1.07  B    
#5 -0.491 -1.11  B  
#....
```

It also comes with argument `.keep` (which is `TRUE` by default) to specify whether or not the grouped column should be kept.

```
df %>% group_split(g, .keep = FALSE)

#[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#       x      y
#   <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 -1.21  -1.45 
#2  0.506  1.10 
#3 -0.477 -1.17 
#4 -0.110  1.45 
#5  0.134 -0.969

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#       x      y
#   <dbl>  <dbl>
#1  0.277  0.575
#2 -0.575 -0.476
#3 -0.998 -2.18 
#4 -0.511 -1.07 
#5 -0.491 -1.11 
#....
```

The difference between `base::split` and `dplyr::group_split` is that `group_split` does not name the elements of the list based on grouping. So

```
df1 <- df %>% group_split(g)
names(df1) #gives 
NULL
```

whereas

```
df2 <- split(df, df$g)
names(df2) #gives
#[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(
      x=rnorm(25),
      y=rnorm(25),
      g=rep(factor(LETTERS[1:5]), 5)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following loop can solve the problem:

```r
data <- data.frame(ID_CODE  = c('001', '001', '001', '002', '002', '003'),
                   Metric1 = c('0.94', '0.68', '0.8', '0.12', '0.56', '0.87'))


for (i in unique(data$ID_CODE)) {
  len <- sum(data$ID_CODE == i)
  df <- data.frame(ID_CODE = rep(i, len), 
                   Metric1 = data[data$ID_CODE == i,"Metric1"])
  assign(paste0("df_", i), df)
}
```

The created data frames are:

```
> df_001
  ID_CODE Metric1
1     001    0.94
2     001    0.68
3     001     0.8
> df_002
  ID_CODE Metric1
1     002    0.12
2     002    0.56
> df_003
  ID_CODE Metric1
1     003    0.87
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `data.table` option, you could also use the `split` function:

> Split method for data.table. Faster and more flexible. Be aware that
> processing list of data.tables will be generally much slower than
> manipulation in single data.table by group using by argument, read
> more on data.table.

Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
dt <- data.table(
  x=rnorm(25),
  y=rnorm(25),
  g=rep(factor(LETTERS[1:5]), 5)
)
dt = dt[sample(.N)]
df = as.data.frame(dt)

fdt = dt[, c(lapply(.SD, as.factor), list(g=g)), .SDcols=x:y]
fdf = as.data.frame(fdt)
sdf = split(fdf, list(fdf$g))
sdf
#> $A
#>                     x                  y g
#> 7    1.78691313680308 -0.694706978920513 A
#> 11  -1.06782370598685  -1.12310858320335 A
#> 17   1.71506498688328  0.426464221476814 A
#> 23   1.22408179743946  0.688640254100091 A
#> 25 -0.560475646552213  -1.68669331074241 A
#> 
#> $B
#>                     x                  y g
#> 3  -0.217974914658295 -0.402884835299076 B
#> 8   0.359813827057364  0.553917653537589 B
#> 10  0.497850478229239 -0.207917278019599 B
#> 14  0.460916205989202 -0.295071482992271 B
#> 18  -0.23017748948328  0.837787044494525 B
#> 
#> $C
#>                    x                   y g
#> 5   1.55870831414912   0.153373117836515 C
#> 6  -1.26506123460653   0.895125661045022 C
#> 9  -1.02600444830724  -0.466655353623219 C
#> 13 0.400771450594052 -0.0619117105767217 C
#> 16 -1.96661715662964   -1.26539635156826 C
#> 
#> $D
#>                     x                  y g
#> 4    0.11068271594512 -0.305962663739917 D
#> 12  0.701355901563686   2.16895596533851 D
#> 21 -0.686852851893526  0.878133487533042 D
#> 22  0.070508391424576  -1.13813693701195 D
#> 24  -0.72889122929114  0.779965118336318 D
#> 
#> $E
#>                     x                   y g
#> 1  -0.625039267849257 -0.0833690664718293 E
#> 2  -0.472791407727934    1.20796199830499 E
#> 15 -0.555841134754075  -0.380471001012383 E
#> 19 -0.445661970099958   0.821581081637487 E
#> 20  0.129287735160946    1.25381492106993 E
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>