# split data frame into two by column value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in R where one of the columns is `gender`. The values of `gender` are factors with "f" or "m" though if the data set is bad, it could be more (for instance NA).

I'm trying to split the data frame into a list of data frames with gender being unique. This way I can run the same models on the different populations.

Is there a better way then basically:

```
dfMale <- mydata[which(mydata$gender == "m"),]
dfFemale <- mdata[which(mydata$gender == "f"),]
dfOther <- mydata[!(1:dim(mydata][1] %in% c(which(mydata$gender == "m"),which(mydata$gender == "f"))]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have a lot at functions subset or split.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
X<-split(df, df$gender)
```

from this question

[Split data.frame based on levels of a factor into new data.frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713294/split-data-frame-based-on-levels-of-a-factor-into-new-data-frames)