# Read a csv file into separate data frames in R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have a large csv file with more than 1M rows and it looks like the following

```
zip,name,age,...
50010,betty,34
50010,roger,28
50011,tom,24,1.73
50011,petet,30,1,81
50014,curie,43,1.63,40000
50014,chris,34,1.72,50000
```

I want to read this file into separated lists or data frames so that each data frame contains rows with same zip code (first column). In the previous example, there will be three data frames with different number of columns. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a large dataframe into a list of data frames based on common value in column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527051/split-a-large-dataframe-into-a-list-of-data-frames-based-on-common-value-in-colu) Or [Split data.frame based on levels of a factor into new data.frames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713294/split-data-frame-based-on-levels-of-a-factor-into-new-data-frames) Or [Split/subset a data frame by factors in one column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327020/split-subset-a-data-frame-by-factors-in-one-column)

Comment: Or [split data frame into two by column value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287706/split-data-frame-into-two-by-column-value)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `split` after reading the dataset

```
lst <- split(df1, df1$zip)
```