# Splitting Data into Groups Using R

Tags: r

```
      anim    wt
1     181.0   0
2     179.0   1
3     180.5   0
4     201.0   1
5     201.5   1
```

If I wanted to split this data set into two group. Once group whose wt value 1 and another whose wt value is 0 how do I do that using R.
I know you have to use the split function. But don't know which parameters to specify.

Comment: You already know which function you have to use. The easiest way then is to check the help page of that function by using either `?split` or `help("split")` to find out more about the parameters you have to use and also some examples. Plus, you could search SO for `[r] split data` to find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713294/split-data-frame-based-on-levels-of-a-factor-into-new-data-frames/9713456#9713456 or other previous question.

Comment: I know that I managed to figure it out using the split function. However before playing around with the split function a bit more it was not splitting the data at all. The description of the fourth parameter was confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the subset function:

```
dat <- read.csv('ex.dat',sep='')
zeroes <- subset(dat,wt==0)
ones <- subset(dat,wt==1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split`.  Please check the `?split` for argument details

```
 split(df, df$wt)
```

If you want it as `two` dataframe objects `df0` and `df1`

```
list2env(setNames(split(df, df$wt), paste0('df', 0:1)), envir=.GlobalEnv)

df0
#   anim wt
#1 181.0  0
#3 180.5  0
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(anim = c(181, 179, 180.5, 201, 201.5), wt = c(0L, 
 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("anim", "wt"), class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```