# Convert a dataframe (the first column is the element, the second is the class to which it belongs) to a list of classes

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df=data.frame(term=c("hello","affirms","allows","hello","always","allows","allows","affirms"),
       class=c("class 1","class 1","class 2", "class 2", "class 2","class 3","class 4","class 
4"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
     term   class
1   hello class 1
2 affirms class 1
3  allows class 2
4   hello class 2
5  always class 2
6  allows class 3
7  allows class 4
8 affirms class 4
```

I would like to obtain a list like this:

```
combinations <- list(
  hello   = c("class 1", "class 2"),
  affirms = c("class 1", "class 4"),
  allows  = c("class 2", "class 3", "class 4"),
  always  = c("class 2")
)
```

The solution presented in [Split data.frame based on levels of a factor into new data.frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713294/split-data-frame-based-on-levels-of-a-factor-into-new-data-frames) won't suit my problem because, if I applied the accepted answer of the mentioned question:

```
X <- split(df, df$class)
Y <- lapply(seq_along(X), function(x) as.data.frame(X[[x]])[, 1]) 
names(Y) <- c("class 1", "class 2", "class 3", "class 4")
list2env(Y, envir = .GlobalEnv)
`class 1`
```

I obtain

```
"hello"   "affirms"
```

which is not the desired result. Anyway, I tried to modify the code in this way:

```
X <- split(df, df$term)
Y <- lapply(seq_along(X), function(x) as.data.frame(X[[x]])[, 2])
```

The result seems to be near to the desired one, but:

```
Y
[[1]]
[1] "class 1" "class 4"

[[2]]
[1] "class 2" "class 3" "class 4"

[[3]]
[1] "class 2"

[[4]]
[1] "class 1" "class 2"
```

How do I know that, for example, `Y[[4]]` corresponds to `hello`, while `Y[[2]]` corresponds to `allows`?

Comment: Isn't `split(df$class, df$term)` what you need?

Comment: @RonakShah, thank you, yes it was what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split` :

```
split(df$class, df$term)

#$affirms
#[1] "class 1"   "class 4"

#$allows
#[1] "class 2" "class 3" "class 4"

#$always
#[1] "class 2"

#$hello
#[1] "class 1" "class 2"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `group_split`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_split(term)
```