# Split a data frame based on some criteria

Tags: r, dataframe

Let say I have below data frame

```
set.seed(100)
DF = data.frame(col1 = 1:10, col2 = sample(letters[1:10], 10))
```

Let define a vector

```
vec = c("c", "a", "b")
```

Now I want to split above `DF` based on the values of the `col2`. Means, in the first part I will have all values of `col2` that are in `vec`, and in the second part the remaining part.

Comment: Try: `split(DF, DF$col2 %in% vec)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/9713294/680068

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to have in the first rows the values that are in vec, you can create two data frames, one that corresponds to the values in vec and one where they're not.

Then, you can concatenate them with rbind:

```
in.vec = DF$col2 %in% vec
new.DF = rbind(DF[in.vec,], DF[!in.vec])
```

where `DF[in.vec,]` selected the rows for which the values of col2 can be found in `vec`.