# How to split a dataframe based on dummy variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I've been checking different questions similar to this one but I didn't find the answer, the only one I found a bit similar was [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713294/split-data-frame-based-on-levels-of-a-factor-into-new-data-frames).

I have a dataframe "df" with some variables called "OrigenDestino", "Operación" and "Tipo Buque". I used the function pd.get_dummies:

```
dum_df = pd.get_dummies(df_notimestamp, columns=["OrigenDestino"], prefix=["Origen and Destino are"] )
dum_df = pd.get_dummies(dum_df, columns=["Operación"], prefix=["Operación is"])
dum_df = pd.get_dummies(dum_df, columns=["Tipo Buque"], prefix=["Tipo Buque is"])
```

Now I have a bigger dataframe with this variables split. What I want to do now is split this dataframe into smaller dataframes based on these variables. For example, I like to have a dataframe where variable: "Tipo Buque is_Ro-Ro Cargo Ship"==1 and ""Tipo Operación is Salida"==1.

Tipo Buque is_Ro-Ro Cargo Ship" are dummy variables ""Tipo Operación is Salida"

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround in this article ([How do I select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-do-i-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)). I'd like to do it automatically based on some dummy variables but looks like I'm not able to do it.