# How to call a variable for a list in a file to make "for loop" in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

I am very new to R and would like to know how to make something like a 'for loop'? How to call the list in my file as a value in a 'for-loop-like' command? This is my Rscript:

```
lapply(file_list, function(df){

data_"df" <- data_col %>% filter(col1 == "df") %>% arrange(desc(col2))

NULL
})
```

However, either the error is in "df" (`unexpected string constant in "  data_"df""`) or if I removed the "`data_`" returns all `NULL`.

In bash script, It would've look something like this:

```
for df in $(cat file_list)
do
    [command that loops for $df] > data_"$df"
done
```

---

**In details**: there are two files, `file_list` and `data_col`.
`file list` contains the following:

```
Name_A
Name_B
Name_C
```

and `data_col`

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name_A | 9 | apple |
| Name_B | 7 | orange |
| Name_C | 8 | banana |
| Name_B | 2 | dragonfruit |
| Name_A | 3 | melon |
| Name_A | 7 | grapes |

Expected output of `data_Name_A`

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name_A | 9 | apple |
| Name_A | 7 | grapes |
| Name_A | 3 | melon |

I will appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split data.frame based on levels of a factor into new data.frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713294/split-data-frame-based-on-levels-of-a-factor-into-new-data-frames)